# trying to figure out how to properly write a select for a dataset

Tags: mysql, database

```
table:
--duedate timestamp
--submissiondate timestamp
--blocksreq numeric
--file clob
--email varchar2(60)
```

Each entry is a file which will take blocksreq to accomplish.  There are 8 blocks allotted per day (but could be modified later).  before i insert into the table, i want to make sure there are enough blocks to accomplish it in the timeframe of NOW() and @duedate

I was thinking of the following, but i think i am doing it wrong:

```
R1 = select DAY(), @blocksperday - sum(blocksreq) as free 
     from table 
     where @duedate between NOW() and @duedate 
     group by DAY() 
     order by DAY() desc

R2 = select sum(a.free) from R1 as a;

if(R2[0] <= @blocksreq){ insert into table; }
```

pardon the partial pseudocode.

SQL FIDDLE:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bda5

**warning:  My sql fiddle has garbage code... as i dont know how to make a lot of test cases.  nor set the duedate to NOW()+5 days**

Comment: @podiluska i was jsut about to edit that. haha

Comment: It's probably best if you give us a sample table and dataset using http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: holy crap. No effin way. That exists too? awwwwww yeaaa

Comment: @hafichuk the only thing i didnt know how to do is say like NOW() + 5days......   so i just said NOW()+5

Comment: Would http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (wasn't sure how partial days were handled so ignored that part)

```
CREATE TABLE `DatTable` (
  `duedate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `submissiondate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `blocksreq` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
) 

SET @duedate:='2012-10-15';
SET @submissiondate:=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SET @blocksreq:=5;

INSERT INTO DatTable(duedate,submissiondate,blocksreq)
SELECT @duedate,@submissiondate,@blocksreq
FROM DatTable AS b
WHERE duedate > @submissiondate
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(blocksreq),0) <= DATEDIFF(@duedate,@submissiondate)*8-@blocksreq;
```

Comment: ive never used coalesce before.  That looks like it could work though.  Ill have to take a look at the having clause a bit more.